# Java Spring Boot problema al generar un Spring Starter Project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-tool-suite

Estoy teniendo problemas para generar un Spring Web Starter en Spring Tool Suite 4.3.1. Después de generar el proyecto, me señala un error en el pom, en la etiqueta de parent. Si ejecuto un Maven Clean me da el siguiente error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0:clean (default-clean) on project DemoWeb: Execution default-clean of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0:clean failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:3.1.0 -> org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:3.0: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:3.0: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:pom:3.0 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org: Unknown host repo.maven.apache.org -> [Help 1]
```

Probé sacando el proyecto del IDE y ejecutando mvn eclipse:clean y mvn clean. Al volver a importar me salta la siguiente ventana:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También probé haciendo un Maven - Update Project... sin éxito, Probé creando el proyecto en Eclipse con complementos de Spring Boot, pero da el mismo error. Probé usando la última versión de Maven y de Java. Adjunto el pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.mitocode</groupId>
<artifactId>DemoWeb</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>DemoWeb</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**EDITADO**

Al hacer limpieza del Eclipse tengo un error más detallado:

```
Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for com.example:DemoWeb:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to transfer org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.1.6.RELEASE from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.1.6.RELEASE from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM
```

Saludos.

Comment: Unknown host parece indicar un problema de conexión. Si haces un ping a repo.maven.apache.org obtenes respuesta, o tuviste algún problema de conexión cuando creaste el proyecto que pudo derivar en eso.

Comment: Hola Juan. No pude hacerle ping a esa ruta, si pude hacerle ping a 199.27.74.129 y perdió todos los paquetes. Por otra parte, si envio la URL por el navegador tengo acceso al directorio. No tengo problemas de conexión, pero estoy conectado a un proxy. Igual tengo el proxy configurado en setting.xml. Saludos.

Comment: No se que es esa ip. El error dice Unkown Host repo.maven.apache.org. Yo puedo hacerle ping sin problema. Proba cambiando el DNS de tu conexión para descartar que sea eso. Podes hacer una prueba seteando los de Google: 8.8.8.8 y  8.8.4.4. https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/

Comment: intenta hacer esto:
Busca en el eclipse la configuración que tienes para nacen y verifica la ruta del nacen, mi recomendación es que quedé siempre en una carpeta raiz, ejemplo c:/tools/M2
Y ejecuta nuevamente el maven clean install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracias a todos por responder. Ya lo resolví. La conexión de internet me estaba bloqueando la descarga en algunos repos. Se solucionó cuando probé con otra conexión de internet.

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

El problema que te indica es que Maven no logro bajar el plugin org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api

```
Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:pom:3.0 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org: Unknown host repo.maven.apache.org -> [Help 1]
```

Ubica la ruta en tu repositorio usualmente seria algo como

```
<home_directory>\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\maven-plugin-api\3.0
```

Elimina el directorio completo, luego trata de ejecutar la compilacion de el proyecto, esto forzaria a maven a bajar la dependencia nuevamente del repositorio

Comment: Te hizo el build ahora si?

Comment: No, el directorio que me señalaste no se encuentra en el .m2, Sin embargo, eliminé el proyecto, cree uno nuevo y me dió un error más detallado. Lo edité en el caso. Saludos.

Comment: La ruta que te indico es de tu maquina, no es del pom, el nuevo error parece tener relacion, tienes problemas a llegarle al repositorio de maven, usas algun proxy?

Comment: Si, utilizo un proxy, pero lo tengo configurado en el setting.xml. Saludos.

Comment: Revisa si tienes la ruta en tu maquina, a veces pasa que maven llega el repo y courre algun error descargando y hay que borrarlos para que maven los descargue nuevamente